# How do I get NetBeans to check HTML syntax in .php web pages files?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and I want it to highlight bad HTML syntax in a .php file. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "hi";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above is missing the > character on the `<head>` tag. In a .html file, NetBeans would flag this. But it does not flag it in a .php file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working, after some seconds of waiting. Using NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Click the lightbulb in the top left of the editor window when looking at a PHP Web Page, and there's an option to add HTML syntax checking. I guess it's just turned off by default.